# Expected to receive a SlashCommandChannelOption builder, got undefined instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

While creating a command using Discord.js v13, I encountered an interesting error that I can't seem to figure out.

If I use a command handling system and create a command with a *channel* input field via the **Application Commands** feature Discord created not so long ago for Developer applications, I run into the following error when running the Node.js application:

```js
F:\Development\eco-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\Assertions.js:44
        throw new TypeError(`Expected to receive a ${instanceName} builder, got ${input === null ? 'null' : 'undefined'} instead.`);
        ^

TypeError: Expected to receive a SlashCommandChannelOption builder, got undefined instead.
    at Object.assertReturnOfBuilder (F:\Development\eco-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\Assertions.js:44:15)
    at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (F:\Development\eco-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\mixins\CommandOptions.js:76:22)
    at MixedClass.addChannelOption (F:\Development\eco-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\mixins\CommandOptions.js:40:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Development\eco-bot\commands\faq.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
```

Before any questions about it are raised, yes all the other commands are properly loaded and sent to Discord's Application Commands API and Discord registers them without errors.

Here's the code that produces the issue:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("faq")
        .setDescription("Send a FAQ question and answer in selected channel")
        .addChannelOption(channel => {
            channel
                .setName("channel")
                .setDescription("Channel you want to send the FAQ embed in")
                .setRequired(true)
        }),
    async execute (interaction) {
        await interaction.reply("Pong! :ping_pong:")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you pass as an argument into `.addChannelOption()` method is expected to return an instance of `SlashCommandChannelOption`, which in your case is `channel`. So make sure to return the `channel`.

[image]

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("faq")
        .setDescription("Send a FAQ question and answer in selected channel")
        .addChannelOption(channel => {
            return channel // Add return here
                .setName("channel")
                .setDescription("Channel you want to send the FAQ embed in")
                .setRequired(true)
        }),
    async execute (interaction) {
        await interaction.reply("Pong! :ping_pong:")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake. In the documentation they omit the curly braces {} so they can implicitly `return` the body of the callback. If you use curly braces you must use `return`